# How to make a racing Bar Chart Visualization in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly-python

how Animated Bar Chart Race Python : How to make a bar change its position automatically. For example, in the below code example while for countries like USA having more values, the bar should gradually move up.

```
import plotly.express as px

import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np 

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'

def read_file(url):
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    return df

def filter_specific_country(df, selected_countries):
    df1=df[df['Country/Region'].isin(selected_countries) ]
    countrywise_grouped_df = df1.groupby(df['Country/Region']).sum().drop(['Lat','Long'], axis=1)
    countrywise_grouped_df
    return countrywise_grouped_df

def transpose_and_reformat_data(df):
    df_t=df.transpose()
    df_t.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_t.rename(columns={'Country/Region':'Index_Col', 'index':'Dates'}, inplace=True)
    return df_t

confirmed_dataset = read_file(url)
selected_countries=['India','China','Italy','Spain','France','Australia','Germany','Japan','Korea, South','Pakistan',
                    'Russia','United Kingdom','Canada','Iran','Brazil','Singapore','South Africa','US']
ds=filter_specific_country(confirmed_dataset,selected_countries)
data=transpose_and_reformat_data(ds).melt(id_vars=["Dates"], var_name="Country", value_name="Confirmed_Count")
#plot_title="Global Spread of Covid-19 : (Selected Countries)"
plot_title='Visualizing the spread of Novel Coronavirus COVID-19 (2019-nCoV) - Created by Dibyendu Banerjee'
fig = px.bar(data, y="Country", x="Confirmed_Count", color="Country",
  animation_frame="Dates", range_x=[1,14000000], orientation='h' )
fig.update_layout(title=plot_title,yaxis_title='Countries', xaxis_tickangle=90, font=dict(family="Arial",size=10,color="#7f7f7f"))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, bar chart tracing using potly is not feasible. There is already a dedicated [library](https://pypi.org/project/raceplotly/) that I will use to answer your question. Since the data is at the daily level, it will take a long time to play back, so I will need to resample or summarize the data into years.

```
from raceplotly.plots import barplot
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'

def read_file(url):
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    return df

def filter_specific_country(df, selected_countries):
    df1=df[df['Country/Region'].isin(selected_countries) ]
    countrywise_grouped_df = df1.groupby(df['Country/Region']).sum().drop(['Lat','Long'], axis=1)
    countrywise_grouped_df
    return countrywise_grouped_df

def transpose_and_reformat_data(df):
    df_t=df.transpose()
    df_t.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_t.rename(columns={'Country/Region':'Index_Col', 'index':'Dates'}, inplace=True)
    return df_t

confirmed_dataset = read_file(url)
selected_countries=['India','China','Italy','Spain','France','Australia','Germany','Japan','Korea, South','Pakistan',
                    'Russia','United Kingdom','Canada','Iran','Brazil','Singapore','South Africa','US']
ds=filter_specific_country(confirmed_dataset,selected_countries)
data=transpose_and_reformat_data(ds).melt(id_vars=["Dates"], var_name="Country", value_name="Confirmed_Count")

covid_race = barplot(data, item_column='Country', value_column='Confirmed_Count',time_column='Dates')
covid_race.plot(item_label='Top 10 crops', value_label = 'Covid Confirmed Count', date_format='%Y/%m/%d', frame_duration=800)
```

[image]

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please click on the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: is there any  libraries in python for race bar

Comment: As indicated in the comments of the answer, there is a library of plotly versions of bar chart tracing. In this case, I installed it and made it happen. If my answer is helpful to you, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the buttons above and below the answer.